# Ceating popup like in Mootools

Tags: jquery, popup, slider

how to create the popup animations like it here 
http://www.unitecms.net/joomla-extensions/unite-responsive-tile-gallery/metro-demo

here is the simple code of images list `[http://jsfiddle.net/L2jhv/]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with jQuery you could build custom animations for each image using [jQuery effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)

Function like (see below) are very handy!

```
.animate()
.fadeIn()
.slideUp()
```

Comment: im not new of useing jquery and know how to build popup but as you can see the images is opening from their positions and going back after closing popup so how to fix image position depending not from screen but website header.

Comment: @user2982337 why don't you look at how they did it?